# Atom Editor: Tag Matching is not working. How do I fix?

Tags: html, tags, atom-editor, matching

[image: Screenshot of my atom editor]

I am new to atom editor and am having an issue with Tag Matching. If you look at my screenshot (see link) you will see that the div tag match on line 44 is correctly highlighted with /div on line 57. After line 57 the highlighting function no longer works. Related to this is the fact that all divs up to line 53 appear in a teal color, thereafter they are all red. Would really appreciate any help on explanations why this is happening and possible fixes. I am running Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You got a `"` which shouldn't be here in the line between lines 53 and 54.

Comment: Thank you Olivier! Careless on my part. I removed the " and all problems solved. So I take it going forwards that if all divs are in red, it means there is an error just prior to that point?